# Using `\mathopen` and friends with `\middle`

Tags: math-mode, scaling

I would like to take advantage of LaTeX's `\left`-`\middle`-`\right` mechanism to automatically scale several parentheses (or something similar) to be the same height, matching the height of the tallest content in any of the parentheses.

I can do this by scaling all of them using `\middle`. However I lose the proper spacing around the parentheses, i.e. they are no longer `\mathopen` and `\mathclose`. Typing something like `\mathopen\middle(` or makes LaTeX throw an error.

Is it possible to declare something `\mathopen` etc. while still using automatic scaling with `\middle`?

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
    \left. \middle( \sum_i a_i \middle) \middle( b + c \middle) \right.
\]

% The following line gives errors
% \[
%   \left. \mathopen\middle( \sum_i a_i \mathclose\middle) \mathopen\middle( b + c \mathclose\middle) \right.
% \]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\left.\middle(` and not `\left(`? In any case, this will give wrong sizes: there's no reason for the parentheses around `b+c` to be the same size of the ones around the summation.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

I think bbb does what you ask, but the automatic size is too big in any case so it looks better if you do ccc with manually chosen size, which also then makes it easy to use the same size in all cases.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

aaa
\[
    \left. \middle( \sum_i a_i \middle) \middle( b + c \middle) \right.
\]

bbb
\[\nulldelimiterspace=0pt
    \left. \mathopen{}\middle( \sum_i a_i \middle)\mathclose{} \mathopen{}\middle( b + c \middle)\mathclose{} \right.
\]

ccc
\[
    \Bigl( \sum_i a_i \Bigr) \Bigl( b + c \Bigr)
\]


\end{document}
```